# How to join multiple condition table in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have `perf_component_valuation` table :
[image]

Then I join it:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ee.first_name,' ',ee.last_name) as valuated_name,CONCAT(ee.first_name,' ',ee.last_name) as valuator_name from emp_employee as ee 
left join perf_component_valuation as pcv on pcv.valuator=ee.employee_id
WHERE pcv.phc_id =49;
```

And try this one:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ee.first_name,' ',ee.last_name) as valuated_name,CONCAT(ee.first_name,' ',ee.last_name) as valuator_name from emp_employee as ee 
left join perf_component_valuation pcv on pcv.valuator=ee.employee_id
left join perf_component_valuation pcv2 on pcv2.valuated=ee.employee_id
WHERE pcv.phc_id =49;
```

But it just give me valuator name only,not valuated.This is the result:
[image]

The result that i want is:

```
valuated_name || valuator_name
______________________________
Adni          || Arli Ramdhani
Adni          || Mohammad Aldo
```

How can i give another condition on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try joining on to emp_employee twice

```
SELECT CONCAT(valuated_ee.first_name,' ',valuated_ee.last_name) as valuated_name,CONCAT(valuator_ee.first_name,' ',valuator_ee.last_name) as valuator_name 
from perf_component_valuation as pcv
left join emp_employee as valuated_ee on pcv.valuated=valuated_ee.employee_id
left join emp_employee as valuator_ee on pcv.valuator=valuator_ee.employee_id
WHERE pcv.phc_id =49;
```

Comment: phew *wipes sweat* hehe

Answer (score 0):

You used one same alias `ee`, try this;)

```
SELECT CONCAT(pcv.first_name,' ',pcv.last_name) as valuated_name,CONCAT(ee.first_name,' ',ee.last_name) as valuator_name from emp_employee as ee 
left join perf_component_valuation as pcv on pcv.valuator=ee.employee_id
WHERE pcv.phc_id =49;
```

Comment: sorry,but `pcv` table didn't have `first_name` and `last_name` column. It just in `ee` table.

Comment: So which columns did you use to get `valuated_name`?